# Why a global object properties aren't updating after function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, html-select

I'm trying to create a game, and the first step of it is the character selection through html-select. When the user chooses an option, through function (including a "switch"), a previously defined object has his values re-assigned, and I can even echo those inside the function, but, when I try the same outside the function the values don't update properly. Here is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var selectedPlayer = {
        level: 0,
        gold: 1,
        expWorth: 0,
        classLevel: 0,
        experience: 0,
        totalHealth: 0,
        totalEnergy: 0,
        totalAttack: 0,
        totalDefense: 0,
        totalSpeed: 0,
        totalFatigue: 0
};

function switchingCharacter() {
  switch ($("#mySelect option:selected").val()) {    
     case "heracles":
      $("#demo2").text("You selected Heracles");
      selectedPlayer = {
        level: 2,
        gold: 2,
        expWorth: 0,
        classLevel: 0,
        experience: 0,
        totalHealth: 35,
        totalEnergy: 10,
        totalAttack: 51,
        totalDefense: 50,
        totalSpeed: 2,
        totalFatigue: 2
      };
      break;
    case "ra":
      $("#demo2").text("You selected Ra");
      selectedPlayer = {
        level: 1,
        gold: 1,
        expWorth: 0,
        classLevel: 0,
        experience: 0,
        totalHealth: 180,
        totalEnergy: 10,
        totalAttack: 13,
        totalDefense: 8,
        totalSpeed: 2,
        totalFatigue: 2
      };
      break;
    default:
      $("#demo2").text("You didn't select any character");
  }

  $("#hp").text("HP: " + selectedPlayer.totalHealth);
  $("#attack").text("Attack: " + selectedPlayer.totalAttack);
  $("#defense").text("Defense: " + selectedPlayer.totalDefense);
  $("#energy").text("Energy: " + selectedPlayer.totalEnergy);
  $("#speed").text("Speed: " + selectedPlayer.totalSpeed);
  $("#fatigue").text("Fatigue: " + selectedPlayer.totalFatigue);
  $("#gold").text("Gold: " + selectedPlayer.gold);
}

function displaystats() {

  $("#level").text("Level: " + selectedPlayer.level);
}
//Below is something added in 2nd edition
  var testing = selectedPlayer.fatigue;
  function other() {
  $("#log").text(Math.floor(testing));
  }
  other();
console.log(testing);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Welcome to Anime Colisseum's System Calculator.</p>

  <p>Select your character below:</p>

  <form>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="switchingCharacter()">
    <option value="heracles">Heracles</option>  
    <option value="ra">Ra</option>
     
  </select>
  </form>

  <p id="demo" class=form-control></p>
  <p id="demo2" class=form-control></p>

</body>
<p id=hp></p>
<p id=energy></p>  
<p id=attack></p>
<p id=defense></p>
<p id=speed></p>
<p id=blocks></p>
<p id=fatigue></p>
<p id=gold></p>
<p id=level></p>
<p id=log></p>  <!-- 2edition --->
</html>
```

I expected that the p element with the "id=level" would be changed, just as the others inside switchingCharacter() were...

I fairly new to programming so is highly probable that I am, perhaps, overlooking a simple but crucial detail. Thanks in advance.

## Now edited: Thanks to the answer provided by Zlatko now I see that I forgot to call the updating stats function inside `switchingCharacter()`. Still, a problem remains, it doesn't seems as if the values I wrote in switchingCharacters() are being properly stored in the selectedCharacter object, `var testing = selectedPlayer.fatigue; function other() { $("#log").text(Math.floor(testing)); } other(); console.log(testing);` By adding this, for example, the console echoes "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a call to `displaystats` - at the end of your `switchingCharacter` function. Here's your code with the line added, now showing level.

To be more specific, you defined a function which will update the stats. But you never called it. That's why it did not work.

---

As an aside, you would usually add all the other displaying of stats in a single function (be it `displaystats`, `render` or whatever). So your code for switching character, it just switches character (and maybe informs some "controller" that there was an update). Your `displaystats` code would just be doing display stats, nothing else, when called. Now, this "controller" could be in charge of when to call which thing - e.g. on an interval, or on certain actions etc.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var selectedPlayer = {
  level: 1,
  gold: 0,
  experience: 0,
  totalAttack: 0,
  totalDefense: 0,
  totalHealth: 0,
  totalEnergy: 0,
  totalSpeed: 0,
  totalBlocks: 0
};

function switchingCharacter() {
  switch ($("#mySelect option:selected").val()) {    
     case "heracles":
      $("#demo2").text("You selected Heracles");
      selectedPlayer = {
        level: 2,
        gold: 2,
        expWorth: 0,
        classLevel: 0,
        experience: 0,
        totalHealth: 35,
        totalEnergy: 10,
        totalAttack: 51,
        totalDefense: 50,
        totalSpeed: 2,
        totalFatigue: 2
      };
      break;
    case "ra":
      $("#demo2").text("You selected Ra");
      selectedPlayer = {
        level: 1,
        gold: 1,
        expWorth: 0,
        classLevel: 0,
        experience: 0,
        totalHealth: 180,
        totalEnergy: 10,
        totalAttack: 13,
        totalDefense: 8,
        totalSpeed: 2,
        totalFatigue: 2
      };
      break;
    default:
      $("#demo2").text("You didn't select any character");
  }

  $("#hp").text("HP: " + selectedPlayer.totalHealth);
  $("#attack").text("Attack: " + selectedPlayer.totalAttack);
  $("#defense").text("Defense: " + selectedPlayer.totalDefense);
  $("#energy").text("Energy: " + selectedPlayer.totalEnergy);
  $("#speed").text("Speed: " + selectedPlayer.totalSpeed);
  $("#fatigue").text("Fatigue: " + selectedPlayer.totalFatigue);
  $("#gold").text("Gold: " + selectedPlayer.gold);
  displaystats();
}

function displaystats() {

  $("#level").text("Level: " + selectedPlayer.level);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <p>Welcome to Anime Colisseum's System Calculator.</p>

  <p>Select your character below:</p>

  <form>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="switchingCharacter()">
    <option value="heracles">Heracles</option>  
    <option value="ra">Ra</option>

  </select>
  </form>

  <p id="demo" class=form-control></p>
  <p id="demo2" class=form-control></p>

</body>
<p id=hp></p>
<p id=energy></p>  
<p id=attack></p>
<p id=defense></p>
<p id=speed></p>
<p id=blocks></p>
<p id=fatigue></p>
<p id=gold></p>
<p id=level></p>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you fast answer, I can't believe how I missed such a thing. But, there is still an issue, it doesn't seems as if the values I wrote in switchingCharacters() are being properly stored in the selectedCharacter object, `var testing = selectedPlayer.fatigue;
  function other() {
  $("#log").text(Math.floor(testing));
  }
  other();
console.log(testing);`

By adding this, for example, the console echoes "undefined"

Comment: That is happening because initially your `testing` variable _is_ empty. You need to call that console.log after you have flipped the dropdown.

Comment: Additionally, you have to actually take a valid prop. It is called `totalFatigue` on the player object, but you just take `fatigue` later in your assignment.